# Bazel build with VueJS failing to resolve package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, vue.js, bazel

I am trying to build a project with Bazel and VueJS. I ran into three core issues:

1. For one, it would seem that Bazel is unable to resolve the package.json file in the apps/projectX subdirectory and kept throwing errors till I moved it out. This is less than ideal for me as I was hoping to have the workspace file do the builds of my separate javascript projects in isolation
2. Even after moving package.json and package-lock.json file to the root and building successfully since it could not reference package-lock.json directly, it generated the pnpm-lock.yaml file but still threw this error: Error in path: Not a regular file: path/to/project/pnpm-lock.yaml

I was expecting to have the WORKSPACE file generate rules that all possible JS projects will use, and the individual BUILD files to be able to use those rules

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.